# Using Microphone in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to create some small voice-controlled game (for windows and  android).
No voice recognition  is needed (yet), only voice volume is important.

So, the task can be reduced to creating a simple  equalizer, which would get voice data from the microphone in real time.

Are there some Unity libraries  for this (reading microphone stream and detecting current volume), or should I look for something external?
Thanks.

Comment: Something like Unity's [Microphone](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Microphone.html)? And: [Scriping](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can find the answer to your question on this [thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/real-time-audio-from-microphone.145686/).

Good luck!